# Definition of sparsity

Tags: sparse-matrices, sparsity

Considering the definition of sparsity in algebra, is it still correct to consider that a matrix / vector is sparse if the position of non-zero elements is known?

Can a time-gating operation then be considered sparsity-driven?

Comment: knowing the position of non-zero elements is called support detection. in general, sparsity means that your signal or object has few nonzero terms, e.g. for a vector to be sparse we expect it's $\ell^0$ pseudo norm to be low or for a matrix to be sparse we want low rank.

Comment: thanks for this first element, it allowed me to orient my research towards new readings thanks to the indicated keywords